# Maximum value of function exists or not

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $ f : [0,\infty) \to\Bbb R $ be a continuous function with $ \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0 $. Then $f$ has maximum value in $[0, \infty)$.
The given satement is false and I am unable to prove it . Also I didn't get any counter example to argue this statement false.

Comment: The statement is false as seen from the counter-example given in the answers here. But if we add the additional hypotheses that $f$ takes some positive value, then $f$ has a maximum.

Answer (score 4):

Take $f(x)=-e^{-x}$ and see what happens.

Comment: Thnks for explaining